# GitLab error on license_scanning. Jobs License-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I hope you’re doing well. I am currently working on a project where we have integrated GitLab CI/CD pipelines for automating various tasks, including license scanning. However, I am facing an issue with the license_scanning job, and I could really use some assistance from the community.

Here’s the error I am encountering:

```
$ cat <<EOF> "$SETUP_CMD" # collapsed multi-line command
$ /run.sh analyze .
Selecting previously unselected package asdf.
(Reading database ... 20275 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../asdf_0.7.8-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking asdf (0.7.8-1) ...
Setting up asdf (0.7.8-1) ...
Running '/opt/gitlab/custom_setup.sh' to install project dependencies…
You must specify a name and a version to install
Unknown release: openjdk-
/opt/gitlab/custom_setup.sh: line 6: mvn: command not found
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:00
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: gl-license-scanning-report.json: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I have included the Security/License-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml template in my .gitlab-ci.yml file, and the license_scanning job is defined with specific settings for license scanning.

Here’s the relevant part of my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
include:
  - template: Security/License-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

license_scanning:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - aker_internal
  needs:
    - Version updates - compile version
  dependencies: []
  variables:
    ASDF_JAVA_VERSION: openjdk-$CI_JAVA_RELEASE
    ASDF_MAVEN_VERSION: $CI_MAVEN_VERSION
    LM_JAVA_VERSION: $ASDF_JAVA_VERSION
    LICENSE_FINDER_CLI_OPTS: '--recursive'
    MAVEN_OPTS: ""
    MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-DskipTests --batch-mode -ntp"
    SETUP_CMD: "/opt/gitlab/custom_setup.sh"
  before_script:
    - |-
      cat <<EOF> "$SETUP_CMD"
      # Install the versions of Maven and Java we use
      asdf install maven $ASDF_MAVEN_VERSION
      asdf install java $ASDF_JAVA_VERSION
      # This is to workaround issue where a GitLab pipeline tries to download our modules from public repositories
      # which does not happen when running the container outside of a pipeline:
      mvn install ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} -Dmaven.test.skip=true -f "$MAVEN_ROOT" ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE:+-s "$MAVEN_ROOT/$MAVEN_SETTINGS_FILE"}
      EOF
      chmod +x "$SETUP_CMD"
  rules:
    - !reference [.workflow_rules, standard_workflow]
```

I suspect that there might be an issue with the custom setup or the availability of Maven (mvn) during the job execution. The job seems to fail when trying to install the project dependencies.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has experience with GitLab CI/CD and license scanning, your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I’m open to any ideas or potential solutions to resolve this issue.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/tree/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs

Thank you all for your time and support!

Best regards,

GitLab pipeline job